# Sort elements in multiple Flexbox rows according to their width/size

Tags: javascript, css, sorting, flexbox, listitem

So let's say I have a set of list items like this (some sort of categories):

```css
ul.categoryList {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 180px;
}

ul.categoryList > li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="categoryList">
  <li>Literature</li>
  <li>Science Fiction and Fantasy</li>
  <li>Harry Potter</li>
  <li>Movies and Films</li>
  <li>Books</li>
</ul>
```

And this `<ul>` is inside a `<div>` with a `max-width` that can change if the window is resized or on different resolution/devices (mobiles, tablets, ...).

As you can see, some of the list items are longer than others. Let's say that the container of this `<ul>` can only contain the list item `Science Fiction and Fantasy` and a bit more, so the next item will go to the next row since it doesn't fit on the same one.

The problem, as you may be able to see, is that `Literature` and `Books` could be together on the same row, but as they are not consecutive, they will end up on separated rows, and the same applies to the other items.

So, instead of putting some of the shortest items together to consume fewer rows, I get 5 rows (one per item, actually), which is space consuming.

Is there any way to fix this? Can it be done with just with CSS or do I need JavaScript?

Comment: You cannot rely on only CSS to rearrange your elements so they take the minum space .. it seems a job for JS

Comment: I was "afraid" of that. Is there some easy javascript solution already made I can look for, or...?

Comment: Such algorithm is common and used everywhere but actually am not able to remember how we call this :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Sort elements by number of characters

You need to use JavaScript to sort your elements according to their length/size.

This is a basic example using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort them according to the number of characters of each of them ([`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)):

```js
// Sort the elements according to their number of characters:

const categoryList = document.getElementById('categoryList');

Array.from(categoryList.children).sort((a, b) => {
  const charactersA = a.innerText.length;
  const charactersB = b.innerText.length;
  
  if (charactersA < charactersB) {
    return -1;
  } else if (charactersA === charactersB) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}).forEach((element) => {
  // When appending an element that is already a child, it will not
  // be duplicated, but removed from the old position first and then
  // added to the new one, which is exactly what we want:
  
  categoryList.appendChild(element);
});
```

```css
#categoryList {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 220px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

#categoryList > li {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="categoryList">
  <li>Literature</li>
  <li>Science Fiction and Fantasy</li>
  <li>Harry Potter</li>
  <li>Movies and Films</li>
  <li>Books</li>
</ul>
```

#### Sort elements by actual width

`innerText` might work fine for monospaced fonts, but for others, you could use [`HTMLElement.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) instead to take into account the actual width of the element:

```js
/**
* Get the actual width of an element, taking into account margins 
* as well:
*/
function getElementWidth(element) {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  
  // Assuming margins are in px:
  return element.offsetWidth + parseInt(style.marginLeft) + parseInt(style.marginRight);
}


// Sort the elements according to their actual width:

const categoryList = document.getElementById('categoryList');

Array.from(categoryList.children).sort((a, b) => {
  const aWidth = getElementWidth(a);
  const bWidth = getElementWidth(b);
  
  if (aWidth < bWidth) {
    return -1;
  } else if (aWidth === bWidth) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}).forEach((element) => {
  // When appending an element that is already a child, it will not
  // be duplicated, but removed from the old position first and then
  // added to the new one, which is exactly what we want:
  
  categoryList.appendChild(element);
});
```

```css
#categoryList {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 220px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

#categoryList > li {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="categoryList">
  <li>Literature</li>
  <li>Science Fiction and Fantasy</li>
  <li>Harry Potter</li>
  <li>Movies and Films</li>
  <li>Books</li>
</ul>
```

#### Sort elements minimizing empty space

You can also implement a custom sorting algorithm to sort them in a different way. For example, you might want to minimize the empty space on each row:

```js
/**
* Get the actual width of an element, taking into account margins 
* as well:
*/
function getElementWidth(element) {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  
  // Assuming margins are in px:
  return element.offsetWidth + parseInt(style.marginLeft) + parseInt(style.marginRight);
}

/**
* Find the index of the widest element that fits in the available
* space:
*/
function getBestFit(elements, availableSpace) {
  let minAvailableSpace = availableSpace;
  let bestFitIndex = -1;
  
  elements.forEach((element, i) => {
    if (element.used) {
      return;
    }
    
    const elementAvailableSpace = availableSpace - element.width;
    
    if (elementAvailableSpace >= 0 && elementAvailableSpace < minAvailableSpace) {
      minAvailableSpace = elementAvailableSpace;
      bestFitIndex = i;
    }
  });
  
  return bestFitIndex;
}

/**
* Get the first element that hasn't been used yet.
*/
function getFirstNotUsed(elements) {
  for (let element of elements) {
    if (!element.used) {
      return element;
    }
  }
}


// Sort the elements according to their actual width:

const categoryList = document.getElementById('categoryList');
const totalSpace = categoryList.clientWidth;
const items = Array.from(categoryList.children).map((element) => {
  return {
    element,
    used: false,
    width: getElementWidth(element),
  };
});
const totalItems = items.length;

// We want to keep the first element in the first position:
const firstItem = items[0];
const sortedElements = [firstItem.element];

firstItem.used = true;

// We calculate the remaining space in the first row:
let availableSpace = totalSpace - firstItem.width;

// We sort the other elements:
for (let i = 1; i < totalItems; ++i) {
  const bestFitIndex = getBestFit(items, availableSpace);
  
  let item;
  
  if (bestFitIndex === -1) {
    // If there's no best fit, we just take the first element
    // that hasn't been used yet to keep their order as close
    // as posible to the initial one:
    item = getFirstNotUsed(items);
    availableSpace = totalSpace - item.width;
  } else {
    item = items[bestFitIndex];
    availableSpace -= item.width;
  }
  
  sortedElements.push(item.element);  
  item.used = true;
}

sortedElements.forEach((element) => {
  // When appending an element that is already a child, it will not
  // be duplicated, but removed from the old position first and then
  // added to the new one, which is exactly what we want:
  
  categoryList.appendChild(element);
});
```

```css
#categoryList {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 220px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

#categoryList > li {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="categoryList">
  <li>Literature</li>
  <li>Science Fiction and Fantasy</li>
  <li>Harry Potter</li>
  <li>Movies and Films</li>
  <li>Books</li>
</ul>
```

#### ✨ Making it look even better

Lastly, you could apply `flex: 1 0 auto` to each child on the list after you have sorted them to remove any irregular empty space between them:

```js
/**
* Get the actual width of an element, taking into account margins 
* as well:
*/
function getElementWidth(element) {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  
  // Assuming margins are in px:
  return element.offsetWidth + parseInt(style.marginLeft) + parseInt(style.marginRight);
}

/**
* Find the index of the widest element that fits in the available
* space:
*/
function getBestFit(elements, availableSpace) {
  let minAvailableSpace = availableSpace;
  let bestFitIndex = -1;
  
  elements.forEach((element, i) => {
    if (element.used) {
      return;
    }
    
    const elementAvailableSpace = availableSpace - element.width;
    
    if (elementAvailableSpace >= 0 && elementAvailableSpace < minAvailableSpace) {
      minAvailableSpace = elementAvailableSpace;
      bestFitIndex = i;
    }
  });
  
  return bestFitIndex;
}

/**
* Get the first element that hasn't been used yet.
*/
function getFirstNotUsed(elements) {
  for (let element of elements) {
    if (!element.used) {
      return element;
    }
  }
}


// Sort the elements according to their actual width:

const categoryList = document.getElementById('categoryList');
const totalSpace = categoryList.clientWidth;
const items = Array.from(categoryList.children).map((element) => {
  return {
    element,
    used: false,
    width: getElementWidth(element),
  };
});
const totalItems = items.length;

// We want to keep the first element in the first position:
const firstItem = items[0];
const sortedElements = [firstItem.element];

firstItem.used = true;

// We calculate the remaining space in the first row:
let availableSpace = totalSpace - firstItem.width;

// We sort the other elements:
for (let i = 1; i < totalItems; ++i) {
  const bestFitIndex = getBestFit(items, availableSpace);
  
  let item;
  
  if (bestFitIndex === -1) {
    // If there's no best fit, we just take the first element
    // that hasn't been used yet to keep their order as close
    // as posible to the initial one:
    item = getFirstNotUsed(items);
    availableSpace = totalSpace - item.width;
  } else {
    item = items[bestFitIndex];
    availableSpace -= item.width;
  }
  
  sortedElements.push(item.element);  
  item.used = true;
}

sortedElements.forEach((element) => {
  // When appending an element that is already a child, it will not
  // be duplicated, but removed from the old position first and then
  // added to the new one, which is exactly what we want:
  
  categoryList.appendChild(element);
});

// If you want to add a class to make the elements inside the list
// expand, you have to do it after sorting them. Otherwise, they would
// already take all available horizontal space and the sorting algorithm
// won't do anything:
categoryList.classList.add('expand');
```

```css
#categoryList {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 220px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

#categoryList > li {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#categoryList.expand > li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="categoryList">
  <li>Literature</li>
  <li>Science Fiction and Fantasy</li>
  <li>Harry Potter</li>
  <li>Movies and Films</li>
  <li>Books</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @DenverDang sorry but this algorithm is not accurate and not correct consdering your requirements ... I thought you are searching to arrange them like this : https://jsfiddle.net/f1x3afpp/ ... to consume the maximum of the space and have the minimum rows. right ?

Comment: Hmmm, but it really seems like it is exactly what it's doing ?
Instead of having several rows with alone items, it now gives be fewer rows with more items in each (depending on size). But maybe I'm missing something ?

Comment: This code is just sorting the elements inside `#categoryList` by the number of characters. With minimum changes, you can update it to sort them by their actual width (using `offsetWidth`) as different characters have different widths on non-monospaced fonts. However, you might want to keep "Literature" in the first position and bring "Movies and Films" to the second one, as those two fit in a single line and the new order would probably be much more similar to the original one than just sorting them all by width.

Comment: Please, take a look to the updated answer. That's what @TemaniAfif meant. As you can see, this way there's less unused space and you need one row less to accomodate the same elements.